# On freenode, how do I keep NickServ from messaging me when I log in?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, irc, empathy

I have Empathy set to run whenever I log in to Ubuntu. As soon as Empathy connects to freenode, I get these messages:

> This nickname is registered. Please choose a different nickname, or identify via /msg NickServ identify .
>
> You are now identified for [my name].

This is pretty annoying, since Empathy handles identification for me anyway. Is there any way to keep this from happening?

Comment: NickServ will do that regardless, but my client puts service messages in channels - does empathy have a similar setting?

Comment: @Phoshi: It doesn't look like it. Empathy is a pretty poor IRC client, but I want to keep all my chat accounts in one place, so I'm stuck with it (it's really nice for non-IRC stuff!).

Comment: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=555051 There is a feature request for this so hopefully it will get fixed in an upcoming release.

Answer (score 1):

Would the `/ignore NickServ` command work? But you won't receive any message no matter what it is.

Comment: I may be an IRC noob, it seems - where do I type the `/ignore` command? If I enter it into any chatroom (using Empathy), I just get "Unknown command; see /help for the available commands", and "/help" doesn't list any "/ignore" command.